# PHP inbox System

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a problem with creating an inbox System. 
What i'm trying to do is in "ViewMessages.php" I am trying to pull information from a MYSQL Table to show messages.

My First Statement is:

```
    $MessageQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE ToUName='$ToUName' AND FromUName='$FromUName'");
```

But I realised a flaw, it will only show  messages sent 1 way. I Tried something like:

```
    $MessageQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE ToUName='$ToUName' AND FromUName='$FromUName' OR FromUName='$ToUName' AND ToUName='$FromUName'");
```

This failed. Can anyone shed some light to show both messages from both parties?

Comment: SQL table structure, or it didn't happen.

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  Don't write new code with `mysql_*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM messages
WHERE '$ToUName' in (ToUName, FromUName)
OR '$FromUName' in (ToUName, FromUName)
```

or if you prefer columns listed first in your query

```
SELECT * 
FROM messages
WHERE ToUName in ('$ToUName', '$FromUName')
OR FromUName in ('$ToUName', '$FromUName')
```

Comment: You have mentioned the PHP $variable in the column place.

Comment: I have just tried this method, i'm using $_GET to get the information for the to and from, and if i modified ToUName to "testing" and kept the FromUName, it returned the results from the old variables.

Comment: SELECT * 
 FROM messages
 WHERE ToUName in ('$ToUName', '$FromUName')
 AND FromUName in ('$ToUName', '$FromUName')

just modified to that and it works. Thankyou

Answer (score 3):

How about union?

```
$MessageQuery = mysql_query("(SELECT * FROM messages WHERE ToUName='$ToUName' AND FromUName='$FromUName') UNION (SELECT * FROM messages WHERE FromUName='$ToUName' AND ToUName='$FromUName')");
```

Note: If you need messages in any particular order, you can use `ORDER BY` at the end of the query, hoping you have something like message_id or timestamp attached to each.

Answer (score 1):

You have boolean operators mixed up, try put some () into that.. (a AND b) OR (c AND d).

Also what you'd acomplish is getting all messages between you and the one other contact. Are you aware of that?

Comment: That's what I want. Its a "view message" script, where you can view the conversation between both parties

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

$MessageQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE ToUName='$ToUName' || FromUName='$FromUName'");